# Javascript: Object's this.var inside jQuery method

Tags: javascript, jquery, oop

I can't figure this one out:

I have a function, e.g.

```
function test () {
  this.rating = 0;
  $j('#star_rating a').click(function() {
    alert(this.rating);
  });
}

var foo = new test();
```

On click it alerts "undefined". What is wrong? Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside the function, "this" is the element which has been clicked on, which is different to "this" outside the function. A simple fix:

```
function test () {
  this.rating = 0;
  var self = this;
  $j('#star_rating a').click(function() {
    alert(self.rating);
  });
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Inside the `.click()` the `this` refers to the item clicked. So the context is different than when you set `rating`. Those two `this`s are different.

You need to conserve the context somehow.

Also, you may want to `return false;` or `event.preventDefault()` if you are clicking on a link and you don't want the page to refresh

```
function test () {

  this.rating = 0;
  var oldThis = this;           // Conserving the context for use inside .click()

  $j('#star_rating a').click(function() {

       alert(oldThis.rating);

       return false; // Use this if you don't want the page to change / refresh
  });
}

var foo = new test();
```

### [Try it out with this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yKkZQ/)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to keep a `this`-like reference around inside an object for use later where `this` will probably mean something else, it's a common trick to assign `this` to a local instance variable. I use `self`.

```
function test () {
  var self = this;
  self.rating = 0;
  $j('#star_rating a').click(function() {
    alert(self.rating);
  });
}

var foo = new test();
```

The advantage of this trick is that inside *all* code in your object - even closures - `self` will always refer to the object. You can also use `this` to refer to whatever it normally means.

Answer (score 1):

Like others have said, "this" is different in test and the anonymous function passed to click().

test is a global function, therefore, "this" is a reference to the window (global) object. What you are actually doing is setting a global variable, probably not an intended side-effect. (use alert(window.rating) to see what I mean)

For your example, there is no need to use "this", though I think your example is just to demonstrate a point. If it were real code, tt should be converted to:

```
function test () {
  var rating = 0;
  $j('#star_rating a').click(function() {
    alert(rating); //Use the closure defined in the outer function
  });
}
```

The point is that you shouldn't use "this" from global functions.

Answer (score 0):

The `this` is different in both cases. Try using breakpoints in firebug to see what they are set to.